# Windows 7 freezing occasionally, Windows update or SSD issue?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, freeze

I recently switched to an SSD drive (as my OS drive) which has been working fine for about 2 months now.

Now last week there was a Windows update, after that update, I noticed that Windows would occasionally freeze for about a minute then go back to normal.

By the time the task manager loads, I can't find a trace of any program consuming high CPU or RAM.

Could it be the new SSD? But then again this only happened after that Windows update last week. I am clueless on how to trace this.

Note: My older HDDs are still connected as secondary drives if that makes a difference. Running SMART on all drives says they're in good health.

Comment: Generic Solution: Have you tried running the system file checker? `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Check our the Event Viewer to see what errors are generated during the "freezes".

Comment: @music2myear literally happened again just a few minutes ago, now I check Event Viewer I see an entry for `avgntflt` with a "Warning" level. I guess this is Avira? But I've had it since forever. Maybe it has issues with the recent Windows update?

Comment: @DxTx I just did that and it returned "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them." with a log file. It could be related although right now I'm leaning towards what I found in the Event View as suggested by music2myear

Comment: If the AV is trying to scan a file that it cannot get a lock on, that could certainly be the culprit. Check your Avira client logs.

Comment: @music2myear It looks like there's really a [conflict](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsofts-april-2019-updates-are-causing-windows-to-freeze/) with the Windows update.

Comment: That's a windows 10 problem, you're running Windows 7.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Windows 7 are included in the article I posted

Comment: My bad, sorry. @IMB